# How to properly apply Hough Circle Transform in iOS environment?

Tags: ios, opencv, objective-c++, hough-transform

First of, I have no experience working in Objective C++.

Like the subjects states, I am trying to implement OpenCV (v3.4.2) Hough Circle Transform into images capture via iOS device. So far, I am able to make the captured photo greyscale. However, when I try to apply circle transform, app crashes. Also, there are syntax errors when I try to draw the recognized circles.

[OpenCV Guide I am following.](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html)

Thank you for your time.

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>
#import "GoCalc2-Bridging-Header.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

@implementation ImageConverter : NSObject

+(UIImage *)ConvertImage:(UIImage *)image {
    cv::Mat mat;
    UIImageToMat(image, mat);

    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(mat, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);

    cv::Mat bin;
    cv::threshold(gray, bin, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY | cv::THRESH_OTSU);

    // Apply a Median blur to reduce noise and avoid false circle detection
    cv::medianBlur(mat, gray, 5);

    // Proceed to apply Hough Circle Transform
    std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;
    HoughCircles(gray, circles, cv::HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,
                 gray.rows/16,  // change this value to detect circles with different distances to each other
                 100, 30, 1, 30 // change the last two parameters
                 // (min_radius & max_radius) to detect larger circles
                 );

    // Draw the detected circles
    for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
    {
        Vec3i c = circles[i];
        Point center = Point(c[0], c[1]); // ERROR HERE: No matching constructor for initialization of 'Point'
        // circle center
        circle( src, center, 1, Scalar(0,100,100), 3, LINE_AA); // ERROR HERE: Use of undeclared identifier 'LINE_AA' and Use of undeclared identifier 'src'
        // circle outline
        int radius = c[2];
        circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(255,0,255), 3, LINE_AA); // ERROR HERE: Use of undeclared identifier 'LINE_AA' and Use of undeclared identifier 'src'
    }

    // Display the detected circle(s) and wait for the user to exit the program
    imshow("detected circles", mat);
    cv::waitKey();

    UIImage *binImg = MatToUIImage(bin);
    return binImg;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `LINE_AA`?
This is what I have done in my app `circle( img, center, 1, cvScalar(255,255,255), 3);`.

Instead of `Vec3i c = circles[i];` you may want to try `cv::Vec3i c = circles[i];`

hope it will help